# How do I read multiple lines and end before a certain string using Scanner in Java?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to read multiple lines from a text file before reaching a certain string, "***", which I would then like to print out. How do I do this?
Code:

```
public void loadRandomClass(String filename) {
    try {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(filename));
        while((scan.hasNextLine()) && !(scan.nextLine().equals("***"))) {
        
        }
        scan.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Something went wrong");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
}
```

I have tried some stuff, but it keeps skipping every 2nd line, starting from the 1st and it doesn't stop before "***".

Comment: Well, you haven't shown any body of the loop, but my guess is that in what you've tried, you've called `nextLine()` again. You should call `nextLine()` *once* per iteration - check whether that line is "***" and use it if not... if you call `nextLine()` twice, the line you're checking against and the line you're using will be different lines...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that scan.nextLine() reads the line and deletes it from the buffer i suppose. Try this:

```java
while(scan.hasNextLine()) {
   String next = scan.nextLine();
   if(next.contains("***") break;
   System.out.println(next);
}
```